# simple function using local

Tags: scheme, local, racket

Why is this function just adding a 1 to a number and completely ignoring the multiplication?

```
   (define (ev  n)
      (local [(define (res l)
                ( * 2 n))]

      (+  1 n)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

… Because you are not calling `res` anywhere. A `local` special form is useful for defining helper procedures, but just that - *defining* them. They'll do nothing if not called explicitly; also notice that the expression `(* 2 n)` is multiplying `n` times two, but you're ignoring the `l` parameter. I'm not sure what you intended to write, perhaps something like this?

```
(define (ev n)
  (local [(define (res l)
            (* 2 l))]

    (res (+ 1 n))))

(ev 3)
=> 8
```